# Android Room & Hilt

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-room, dagger-hilt

I'm getting an error while developing a project in Android Studio. What could be the reason for this?

I encountered this error while using Hilt, and I couldn't understand the reason.

Take a look at the attached code.

```
@Dao
interface Product Dao {
                
        @Query("SELECT price FROM products") 
        suspend fun getTotalAmount(): List<Double>
    
        @Query("SELECT isFavorite FROM products") 
        suspend fun getFavorite(): List<Boolean>
    
        @Query("SELECT * FROM products")
        fun getAllCart(): LiveData<List<ProductModel>>
    
        @Insert
        suspend fun insert(productModel: ProductModel)
    
        @Query("DELETE FROM products WHERE id = :uid") 
        suspend fun delete(uid: Int)
}
```

---

```
class Converters {
       private val gson
       Gson(){}
                    
       @TypeConverter
       fun fromProductsItem(item: ProductsItem): String {
           return gson.toJson(item)
       }
                  
       @TypeConverter
       fun toProductsItem(itemString: String): ProductsItem {     
           return gson.fromJson(itemString, ProductsItem::class.java)
       }
}
```

---

```
@Dao
interface FavoriteDao {
       @Query("SELECT * FROM favorite")|
       suspend fun getAllFavorite(): List<Favorite Model>

       @Query("SELECT * FROM favorite WHERE uid = :id")
       fun getCurrentFavorite(id: Int) : FavoriteModel?
       
       @Insert
       suspend fun insertFavorite (favoriteModel: FavoriteModel)

       @Query("DELETE FROM favorite WHERE uid = :id")
       suspend fun delete(id: Int)
}
```

Comment: Ok please, remove the images, post the code itself and also the error (all in text)

Comment: If you want to understand the errors, you have to find them first. You posted an image of two warnings, those are not fatal. There are other 20 errors hiding somewhere, go take a look at them.

Comment: Do not place external links, it will make people not to open them(commonly)